# Looking for a kid's book, might be really obscure

Tags: story-identification, space

A long time ago, I read a book involving a small group of kids aboard a spaceship, and they encounter a sentient being in their ship's computer. The being turns out to (somehow) be a small boy from the ancient Egyptian period. The main chatacter's name is Kate Olafson (or Olafsson), and she is the caretaker the younger children. There might also be a cat. Based on what I remember of the cover art, the book is likely from the 70's or early 80's. Google, Amazon and WorldCat searches have all yielded nothing.

Answer (score 7):

Could this be *[Ashar of Qarius](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0152004092)*?

[image]

From Amazon:

> Along comes Ashar of Qarius, the thinking, feeling, and talking
>   computer that presents further problems--whether it's friend or foe,
>   and its connection to the planet's pyramids and ancient Egypt.

So the computer appears to be Egyptian.

Most relevant, the **main character's name [is Kate Olafson](https://archive.org/stream/Aboriginal_Science_Fiction_22v04n04_1990-07-08/Aboriginal_Science_Fiction_22v04n04_1990-07-08_djvu.txt)**:

> The story begins at the newly  founded human colony on Plioctis.  Kate
>   Olafson and five-year-old William Pitt leave the dome to chase
>   after  Kate’s cat, Timmy, but when they  return to the dome, they find
>   it abandoned. They soon find out that the  rest of the colony has
>   been kidnapped by insectoid aliens. Then a strange  being contacts
>   Kate and William via  their computer, a being who gives its  name as
>   Ashar and will say only that it is coming.

And as we can see from the cover, there is *indeed* a cat.